# Inno Setup wizard change page after user input

Tags: inno-setup, wizard

I want to make a wizard. When the user choose yes, then the page x should follow. When the user choose no, then the page y should follow. At the moment it is only working for me with static pages, so it does not matter, what the user chooses always the same page follows... how can I change this? Please have somebody an idea?

Here is an extract:

```
ExistPage := CreateInputOptionPage(OldPage.ID,
  '', '', 'If you choose "Yes" then the package will be installed automatically with this setup',True, False);
// Add items
ExistPage.Add('Yes');
ExistPage.Add('No');
// Set initial values (optional)
ExistPage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;

TexPage := CreateInputDirPage(ExistPage.ID,
'Root installation directory', 'Please select installation directory',
'',
True, 'New Folder');
TexPage.Add('');
// Set initial value (optional)
TexPage.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('C:\');
```

Comment: I guess you mus use `CurPageChanged` and examine the `CurPageID` to see which page you are on. Then you can test the values made by the user and proceed. Or you might need to use `CurStepChanged` and looking up `CurStep`. I know that others will have more knowledge about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your page you can store the page ID into a variable:

```
// InitializeWizard is called when the wizard is about to begin.
// This is where we add any custom pages into the installation process.
// The relevant XXX_CreatePage methods should be defined BEFORE this method.
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    // Add the Application Settings page just after the Selected Tasks page
    idAppSettingsPage := AppSettings_CreatePage(wpSelectTasks)
end;
```

If you were to cache the result of your users radio choice into a public variable then you might be able to use this:

```
    function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
    // We don't want to show the select dir, select program group or application settings
    // pages if we are upgrading.
    if ((PageID = wpSelectDir) or (PageID = idAppSettingsPage) or (PageID = wpSelectProgramGroup)) then
        Result := bIsUpgrading
    else
        Result := False;
    end;
```

This is something I have used in my setup to selectively show pages during the install process. I am just not sure how you check for a custom page ID.

I am just showing the mechanics. If you know you are now about to show page Y, you can decide to show it if variable AA was set to 1. Make sense?

Comment: Great! Thank you! :-)